# Active Directory Account Locked, Attempts Every 60 Seconds From Exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange

After a password change on *my* account, I keep getting locked out by exchange with this error on our domain controller:

```
Pre-authentication failed:
User Name:  william
User ID:        [domain]\william
Service Name:   krbtgt/[domain]
Pre-Authentication Type:    0x2
Failure Code:   0x18
Client Address: [exchange IP]
```

I've already looked into:

- My cellphone, updated the account, and even removed the account.
- Services/tasks on the server running as me (there are none).
- SMTP traffic to the mail server (there is none during this).
- Any requests to the server (using wireshark, the kerberos request just comes out of nowhere every 60 seconds).
- Disabled pre-auth on the account.
- Rolled back my password to the old password.
- Disconnecting my mailbox.

Any ideas? I'm looking to schedule a reboot tonight, but this is *rough*, I can't get anything done.

Comment: Look at your desktop (assume Windows 7) | Control Panel | Windows Card Space. Do you have anything cached ? if so remove it.

Comment: Nope, don't have any cards to cache.

Comment: Other software or services on the Exchange server that would use your account?  Still logged in to an old RDP session?

Comment: Logged out of all RDP sessions, verified from 2nd account. No software or services running as my account.

Comment: In your Exchange mailbox, any additional mobile devices?  Maybe an iPad or similar?  If not, that's all I can think of.

Comment: Removed all devices from my Exchange mailbox just to be sure (had my old phone on there too).

Comment: If it really bugs you that much, create a GPO to override the default Account Lockout Policy settings. You can use the `badPasswordTime` attribute on your user account to see whether the issue persists while you troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be AppAssure, it doesn't throw any errors when auth fails, and it doesn't log anything when it can't mount the exchange datastore, so looking through services/event logs/tasks/AppAssure console didn't show anything.

Comment: Backup Software should definitely not be running as your user account, nor any user's account. It should have it's own service account (if it can't run as the local system).

Comment: It wasn't running as, which made it harder to hunt down, it was credentials internally it used for mounting and checking the exchange datastore, which I believe needs exchange management roles.